# Showing with only primitive rules?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

How do I prove the following using the natural deduction system, utilizing solely primitive rules?

> $\vdash \,[(B \supset A) \vee B]$

Comment: Which system? Fitch or hilbert?

Comment: What is $\supset$?

Comment: @KennyLau $\supset$ is an old school symbol for material implication.

Comment: There are many different sets of 'primitive rules' ... you really need to indicate what specific rule you have, otherwise we are just guessing.  And even more importantly, have you tried anything yourself? Please add your own efforts to the Post. In fact, from your attempt, we already get a much better idea as to what rules you are supposed to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this statement is not true in intuitionistic logic (frames $0 \longrightarrow 1$ with nothing known at $0$ and $B$ known at $1$), so you need the law of the excluded middle.

1) $B \lor \neg B$ (LEM)

2) $B$ (assumption)

3) $(B \to A) \lor B$ (disjunction introduction from 2)

4) $B \to (B \to A) \lor B$ (implication introduction, discharge 2)

5) $\neg B$ (assumption)

6) $B$ (assumption)

7) $\bot$ (contradiction introduction from 5 6)

8) $A$ (explosion, discharge 7)

9) $B \to A$ (implication introduction, discharge 6)

10) $(B \to A) \lor B$ (disjunction introduction from 9)

11) $\neg B \to (B \to A) \lor B$ (implication introduction, discharge 5

12) $(B \to A) \lor B$ (disjunction elimination, from 1 4 11)

Comment: More pointedly, the substitution instance with $A=\bot$ and using the typical definition $\neg A\equiv A\to\bot$ is exactly the law of the excluded middle: $\neg B\lor B$.

Comment: @DerekElkins how is that the law of the excluded middle?

Comment: I could have added some punctuation to make the sentence structure clearer (or reorganized it). I'm saying $(B\to A)\lor B$ with $A=\bot$ is LEM if our definition of $\neg P$ is $P\to\bot$.

Comment: @DerekElkins oh, I see now.